# Lenovo TB-9707F Y700 How can I remount /Vendor as read write

Tags: root-access, mount

**My device is rooted** but as of yet I don't have TWRP recovery.

I'm trying to change a file in the `/vendor/etc` folder. I'm getting an error that it is a read only system.

How can I  mount it as read write? If not how can I change a file in there?

I found that the `/vendor` folder is a mountpoint for /dev/block/dm-3. I tried to mount this device at `/mnt/ven` but I'm getting the error `Device or resource busy`. This is what I'm trying `mount -t ext4 /dev/block/dm-3 /mnt/ven`.

What can I do to be able to change a file under `/vendor`.

I would be willing to try to change this file by mounting an image of `/vendor` but after coping the `dm-3` device with `dd if=/dev/block/dm-3 of=/data/data/com.termux/files/home/vendor.img` I can't get it to mount. I have tried the following:

```
   1. 
TB-9707F:/ # mount -v -t ext4 /data/data/com.termux/files/home/vendor.img  /mnt/ven
try '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/vendor.img' type 'ext4' on '/mnt/ven'
try '/dev/block/loop0' type 'ext4' on '/mnt/ven'
mount: '/dev/block/loop0'->'/mnt/ven': Invalid argument

   2. 
TB-9707F:/ # losetup -f /data/data/com.termux/files/home/vendor.img
TB-9707F:/ # losetup -a
/dev/block/loop0: [64518]:20323 (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/vendor.img)
TB-9707F:/ # mount -v -o loop /dev/block/loop0 /mnt/ven
try '/dev/block/loop0' type 'ext3' on '/mnt/ven'
try '/dev/block/loop0' type 'ext2' on '/mnt/ven'
try '/dev/block/loop0' type 'ext4' on '/mnt/ven'
try '/dev/block/loop0' type 'vfat' on '/mnt/ven'
try '/dev/block/loop0' type 'msdos' on '/mnt/ven'
try '/dev/block/loop0' type 'exfat' on '/mnt/ven'
mount: '/dev/block/loop0'->'/mnt/ven': I/O error
```

I'm not sure what the argument should be in example 1, or what the I/O Error is in example 2.

From reading about on Google I got the impression that the `dm` devices aren't regular block devices. I haven't been able to figure out what they nor how to mount them.

Comment: Maybe a dumb suggestion- On my Pixel6a I can access vendor partition with a root explorer

Comment: I have tried with root but keep on getting the error that it's a read only system. If root explorer would be free I would try it but since I don't have much confidence that it could do more than other root options I don't want to pay.

Comment: Mix explorer on XDA is free

Comment: Link https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-2-2-mixplorer-v6-x-released-fully-featured-file-manager.1523691/&ved=2ahUKEwj86qyTxb6AAxVMpVYBHY4xDe0QFnoECBkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3q6OF3cSVPXxL6dQ2WzH3b

Comment: @beeshyams I tried MixExplorer and got an error message `couldn't save file`. This is a read only system without remounting as read write I don't think any app will be able to make it work.